# Runtime Polymorphism in Swift Structs

Tags: swift, struct, polymorphism

I'm trying to iterate over two different kinds of structs as shown at the end of the following example. But, for some reason, 'A' and 'B' do not conform to upperCase_Conformance.

Is there another way of achieving this sort of runtime polymorphism?

I essentially just need a way to fit both 'A' and 'B' objects into one list so I can iterate over them and call their printMe() function regardless of actual type.

```
/// lowerCase objects must have a value and an action to perform using that value
protocol lowerCase_Conformance {
    var value: Double { get set }
    init(val: Double)
    func compute() -> Double
}

/// upperCase objects must store a lowerCase object and a way to display the computations being done by the lowerCase object.
protocol upperCase_Conformance {
    var myVal: lowerCase_Conformance { get set }
    init(val: lowerCase_Conformance)
    func printMe()
}



/// Squared operator
struct a: lowerCase_Conformance {
    public var value: Double
    public init (val: Double) {
        self.value = val
    }
    public func compute() -> Double {
        return self.value * self.value
    }
}

/// Housing for the Squaraed operator
struct A: upperCase_Conformance {
    public var myVal: a
    public init (val: a) {
        self.myVal = val
    }
    public func printMe() {
        print("\(self.myVal.value) Squared is \(self.myVal.compute())")
    }
}

/// Incrament operator
struct b: lowerCase_Conformance {
    public var value: Double
    public init (val: Double) {
        self.value = val
    }
    public func compute() -> Double {
        return self.value + 1
    }
}

/// Housing for the Incrament operator
struct B: upperCase_Conformance {
    public var myVal: b
    public init (val: b) {
        self.myVal = val
    }
    public func printMe() {
        print("\(self.myVal.value) Incramented is \(self.myVal.compute())")
    }
}

var workToDo: [upperCase_Conformance] = [
    A(val: a(val: 2)),
    A(val: a(val: 4)),
    B(val: b(val: 2)),
    B(val: b(val: 4))
]

for item in workToDo {
    item.printMe()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is that you're tying to force Object Oriented Program into Swift.

However, if you re-format your code to more closely resemble Protocol Oriented Programing, the issue goes away.

```
protocol Computable {
    func compute() -> Double
}

protocol Printable {
    func printMe()
}



/// Squared operator
struct a: Computable {
    public var value: Double
    public init (val: Double) {
        self.value = val
    }
    public func compute() -> Double {
        return self.value * self.value
    }
}

/// Housing for the Squaraed operator
struct A: Printable {
    public var myVal: a
    public init (val: a) {
        self.myVal = val
    }
    public func printMe() {
        print("\(self.myVal.value) Squared is \(self.myVal.compute())")
    }
}

/// Incrament operator
struct b: Computable {
    public var value: Double
    public init (val: Double) {
        self.value = val
    }
    public func compute() -> Double {
        return self.value + 1
    }
}

/// Housing for the Incrament operator
struct B: Printable {
    public var myVal: b
    public init (val: b) {
        self.myVal = val
    }
    public func printMe() {
        print("\(self.myVal.value) Incramented is \(self.myVal.compute())")
    }
}

var workToDo: [Printable] = [
    A(val: a(val: 2)),
    A(val: a(val: 4)),
    B(val: b(val: 2)),
    B(val: b(val: 4))
]

for item in workToDo {
    item.printMe()
}
```

In Protocol Oriented Programing, protocols should not be treated as "Parent Structs" that Child Structs inherit from. They should just outline the functionality you're trying to capture with that protocol.